# Aliexpress scraping not working from the below url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def aliexpress_scraper(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    c=r.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

    div_tags = soup.find_all("div", class_="sku-property-image")
    return div_tags
```

Url i am scraping:

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32837141232.html?spm=a2g0o.tm65298.p99adbb.14.6c3e5cd3y0piaM&gps-id=5868145&scm=1007.20675.119047.0&scm_id=1007.20675.119047.0&scm-url=1007.20675.119047.0&pvid=674dfb56-da8c-4324-9a87-7f59fc0ae428
```

Here i am tring to **scrape** images from aliexpress.com from above url. But, i it is giving me empty list.

In inspect sku-property-image i can see but in view source it is not showing.

Is there any way to achive that ?

Please have a look

Comment: fyi it's __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapping